# How to prevent parameters created with Scripted Pipeline to replace the ones set on the UI?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

With Jenkins Declarative Pipeline syntax, in the `parameters` block, the behavior of the parameters is like so:

1. If the `defaultValue` of the parameter is customized in the Jenkins UI, it will take precedence over the `defaultValue` in the Jenkinsfile.
2. It will not remove the parameters which are not defined in code but are set in the UI.

However, if I set any parameters using `properties` in a scripted pipeline, the `defaultValue` set in the UI gets replaced (1) and parameters not set gets deleted (2).

Comment: That's pretty standard behavior across ant, maven, etc. Doubt there's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this by editing xml definitions, it turns out that there is parameter declaration under `<actions>` too and removing parameters there fixed this for me. That is the parameters are still under `<properties>` tag but not under `<actions>` anymore and it works.